# Reading keyboard input

Tags: serial

I'm using Serial.read(); to read keyboard input from the serial monitor. 
It only sends the characters after hitting enter or clicking the "send" button.
Is there a way to read keyboard input without having to use "enter"?

Answer (score 1):

Not with the Serial Monitor built into the Arduino IDE. It is possible to use an external terminal program with buffering disabled though.